# How to identify when to give a two for one offer in Java

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing some code for a simple till system. I currently have an `ArrayList` of Vegetables. Vegetables have just a name and a price as parameters.

```
    vegList.add(new Vegetable("Aubergine", 1.50));
    vegList.add(new Vegetable("Tomato", 1));
    vegList.add(new Vegetable("Cucumber", 0));
```

and currently have three Aubegines and one Tomato in my shopping trolley.

I have a method which identifies the name of the vegetable in the trolley and then returns the price but my problem is... I have three Aubergines and have been told that Aubergines are two for £1.

How can I modify my method to say that when my quantity variable reaches two change the price parameter to 1 and then continue on adding Aubergines at £1.50 after until of course reaching a multiple of 2 again (in this case four). See code below...

```
  public double getVegetablePrice(String name) {
    // Iterate through ArrayList
    // Get current index
    // Get Fruit name
    // Get price based on Fruit name
    // return price of Fruit

    double price = 0;
    double count = 0;
    double quantity = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < vegList.size(); i++){
        Vegetable tempVeg = vegList.get(i);

        if(tempVeg.getName() == name){
            if(name.equals("Tomato")) {
                count = tempVeg.getPrice();
                price += (count * 1.0); //£1 per kg
            }

            else if(name.equals("Aubergine")) {
                quantity++; //ADD TO QUANTITY
                if(quantity == 2) {
                    price = 1.0;
                }
                else {
                    price = tempVeg.getPrice();
                }
            }
        }

        else{
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    return price;
}
```

Please note that I'm writing this for a JUnit test which will `assertTrue(vegTotal == 3.50)` and am currently getting a total of £5.50.

Comment: So I can get two for £1 or one for £1.50?  If I buy two, do I have to eat them both?

Comment: One of guava's [`MultiSet`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) would help you count the things.

Answer (score 0):

For aubergines, the quantity for pricing should be:

```
int pricingQuantity = quantity / 2 + quantity % 2;
```

How you incorporate that I leave to you.

---

There are some flaws in your design that are making your code messy. Consider having a class for your grocery items that has a "n for 1" value, and another class for cart item that has a price method that uses the above calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit from having a `ShoppingCart` class that wraps your `ArrayList` plus controls the quantities when adding items to the cart. This way you can simplify the calculation of bundles of items like in your scenario.

For example, a simple (note: not tested) implementation to address your case could be:

```
class ShoppingCart
    private List<Vegetable> items;
    private Map<String, Integer> quantities;

    public ShoppingCart() {
        items = new ArrayList<Vegetable>();
        quantities = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public addItem(Vegetable v) {
        items.add(v);
        //Update quantities
        if (quantities.containsKey(v.getName()) {
            quantities.put(v.getName(), ++quantities.get(v.getName()));
        } else {
            quantities.put(v.getName(), 1);
        }
    }

    //TODO: Implement removeItem() and decrement quantities

    public Double getItemPrice(Vegetable v) {
        return items.contains(v) ? v.getPrice() : 0;
    }


    public Double getItemPrice(Vegetable v) {
        itemPrice = getItemPrice(v);

        if (itemPrice > 0) {
            int quantity = quantities.get(v.getName());

            if (v.getName().equals("Aubergine")) {
                int bundles = quantity / 2;
                int remaining = quantity % 2;
                return bundles * 1 + remaining * itemPrice; 
            }

            //do the rest of the code here

        }
    }

}
```

But you should also have the logic of the "bundle" pricing implemented in your `Vegetable` class. Ideally you should make `Vegetable` an abstract class and have each of your vegetables be a class that implements it.

For example, if you make `Aubergine` a class that implements `Vegetable`, you could create an abstract method `getBundlePrice(int quantity)` that `Aubergine` implements to define its price of 1 for a quantity parameter 2.

This way, you don't need to have all the checks for the vegetable type in your `getItemPrice()` method. Instead, you could just call `v.getBundlePrice(quantity)` to compute it automatically.

Hope it helps.